# jquery dynamic strike not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am inserting dynamically a strike element, but it is rendering in the HTML markup but not showing up visually. The Chrome inspector shows that the strike element is added. Is it because I am adding it around input elements?

Here's the jQuery

```
$("#ResidentialStandardPeriod").change(function () {
    period = $("#ResidentialStandardPeriod").val();
    console.log(period);
    if (period == $('#' + period).attr('id')) {
        $('#' + period).attr('disabled', true).wrap("<strike>")
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + period).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: strike is deprecated in html5. what about apply css 'text-decoration: line-through'?

Comment: I tried that, but the code renders only in the markup. It does not render visually.

Comment: can you please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Here's a buggy implementation of it. http://jsfiddle.net/4xpy8/.
It's a little tricky to implement it in jsfiddle since my application is connected to a database.

Comment: You forgot to assign `id="Period"` to your `select` element

Comment: Here's the udpated code. The <del> does not render for some reason.  http://jsfiddle.net/4xpy8/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap `input` element with `</del>`, coz that wont show any effect on input
but you can wrap next element, in your case `number`.
I would prefer you to wrap your number in `<span>` and then target that span.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="1"><span>1</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="2"><span>2</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="3"><span>3</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="4"><span>4</span><br>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('#Period').change(function(){
        period = $('#Period').val();
        $("span").unwrap();
        console.log(period);
        if (period == $('#'+period).attr('id')){
            $('#'+period).attr('disabled',true).next("span").wrap("<del/>");
            $('input[type=checkbox]').not('#'+period).attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xpy8/3/)**